# Where are the "band names" of an ENVI file once it is imported in R?

Tags: raster, r, envi, stack

I have a .dat file (ENVI format) with specific band names, as you can see in the snapshot.

[image: ENVI snapshot]

I've imported this file in R, but I cannot find the band names in the R object.
The command

```
names(stack_NDVI)
```

gives this output

```
[1] "old_min_identification_VI_smooth_2010.1"  "old_min_identification_VI_smooth_2010.2" 
 [3] "old_min_identification_VI_smooth_2010.3"  "old_min_identification_VI_smooth_2010.4" 
 [5] "old_min_identification_VI_smooth_2010.5"  "old_min_identification_VI_smooth_2010.6"
```

that is not correspondent to the band names of the .dat file as I can see in ENVI.

Any ideas to get this information fro the R object?

I've imported the .dat as a `RasterStack` object.

Comment: Band names are a tricky thing :( Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763013/r-write-rasterstack-and-preserve-layer-names

Comment: Do you have a .hdr with the .dat file?

Comment: @Iris yes I have the .hdr. All the band names are stored there.

Comment: I think it is easiest to copy the band names from the hdr file and rename the band names of the `rasterstack` afterwards using `names(stack_NDVI) <- c('a','b','c')`

Comment: Smart hint. If you will make an "official" answer I will upvote you :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the troubles myself and couldn't find a solution. To export and import rasters between ENVI and R and keep the band names seems impossible (cf. [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763013/r-write-rasterstack-and-preserve-layer-names)).

A workaround is to copy the band_names from the `.hdr` file and rename the band names from the imported `rasterstack`.

`band names = {a,b,c}` copied from `file.hdr`

```
image <- stack("file.dat") 
band_names = c('a','b','c')
names(image) <- band_names
```

Comment: cannot upvote because I need 15 points of reputation...